# Are weaves stable in higher dimensions?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-topology

A textile weave is  stable object in three dimensions. A table cloth is an example. Here is an example of a weave from wikimedia:

[image]

1 - Are weaves (woven from one-dimensional threads) stable in higher dimensions? By "stable" I mean: does a weave stay a weave when it is pulled? Does it remain a weave or does it untangle?

Probably this first question is equivalent to the following one:

2 - Are braids stable in higher dimensions? Do braids remain braids when the ends are pulled?

Comment: Define "braid" in higher dimension.  Define "stable" in higher dimension.

Comment: In $\ge4$ dimensions, 1-dimensional strings do not constrain each other at all.

Comment: Your weave is but a knot, and knots don't exist in higher dimensions.